# On clicking the button dialog is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I  have created the button but when I click on the button it is not showing my dialog.
The button is shown that it clicks but nothing appears. I am trying to show a ⚠ dialog

Here my code
**XML**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/submitB"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/option_button"
        android:text="@string/submit" />
```

**XML** under the LinearLayout

**JAVA**

```
private Button submitB;
submitB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitB);

submitB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitTest();
        }
    });
}
private  void submitTest()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionsActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout,null);

     Button cancelB= view.findViewById(R.id.cancle);
     Button confirmB= view.findViewById(R.id.confirmB);
     builder.setView(view);
     AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
    cancelB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `show()` on your `alertDialog` object

```
private  void submitTest()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionsActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout,null);

     Button cancelB= view.findViewById(R.id.cancle);
     Button confirmB= view.findViewById(R.id.confirmB);
     builder.setView(view);
     AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
     cancelB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         alertDialog.dismiss();
         }
     });

     alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `show()` method to show your Dialog.

I suggest you this syntax which I use to show an AlertDialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(CompileModuleActivity.this)
             .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.success))
             .setMessage(myMessage)
             .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check)
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          finish();
                        }
              })
             .show();
```

Of course you can create a `NegativeButton` or `NeutralButton` to make the dialog dismiss. I just put finish() for my purpose.

Comment: it is not work it show `Cannot resolve method 'show()'`

Comment: The method show() must be called on your AlertDialog, so in your example `alertDialog.show()`